# How do I stop unwanted spaces in Mathematica cells styled as text?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, formatting, style

**Context**: I am working in a Mathematica notebook (I am using 14.0, but the problem to be described was observed in earlier versions.  At some time in the past, though, it was not happening.)

**Problem to be solved**: I type a Mathematica expression and evaluate it. All good. Maybe even do that a few times. New input and output cells are creatd.

Eventually have a new empty input cell and I start typing some annotation. I realize at some point that this is being interpreted as input, and so I hit (on the Mac) Command-7, which changes the style to Text. However each word now has multiple spaces between it.

**Sidebar**: Command-7 is equivalent to a subcommand under menu bar Format->Style.

**Comment**: The idea of a notebook is to intersperse code and text cells. So this should be easy as it once was. I could cut to a text editor, fix, and paste back. But that's awkward and slow. I could also remember to switch to a Text style cell before I start typing, but sometimes (often) I forget. Seems like I should be able to correct for that easily.